# How to arrange in a csv document the label values of several GCP projects

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, jq, gcloud

My problem here is that the labels of every projects are not the same number or keys.
So, I need to retrive all the labels of every project I have access and put it together in a CSV document.

Right now Im trying with
`gcloud projects list --format="csv[no-heading](labels)"`
to get them, but as I said, the problem is how I get the column names across all the projects and then how should I put the values to fit.

The result of the above command is a list of key=value separated by ";" that I do not how to arrange correctly.

I have tried with `--format="json" | jq -r '.[].labels'` and formating the output, but I get to the same problem on how to fix all the keys across all the projects.

Maybe I'm just tired and should rest, but any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Not everyone will be familiar with the output of `gcloud projects list --format="json"`. If you show the output of the command ([perhaps simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), i.e., the input JSON to `jq` and tell us what the output you would like `jq` to produce, we will be able to help.

Comment: @sudocracy the output of the above command is a common json.
```{ "projectId": "my-proyect", "labels": { "label1": "some_value",..., "labelN": "other_value"}}```
You could filter further with ```--format="json(labels)"``` to get only a part of the data.
But the problems is not all the projects have the same number of labels.
Thanks for comment.

Comment: I have added an answer. Let us know if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the output you want for the following input:

#### Output

```
"windy-bearing-129522","env","test"
"windy-bearing-129522","version","alpha"
"canvas-syntax-130823","env","test"
"canvas-syntax-130823","version","beta"
```

#### Input

```json
[
  {
    "labels": {
      "env": "test",
      "version": "alpha"
    },
    "projectId": "windy-bearing-129522",
  },
  {
    "labels": {
      "env": "test",
      "version": "beta"
    },
   "projectId": "canvas-syntax-130823"
  }
]
```

#### Solution

This would work ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JEjS4zkM0Js)):

```bash
jq --raw-output '.[] | { projectId, label : (.labels | to_entries) [] } |
                       [.projectId, .label.key, .label.value ] | @csv   '
```

Readable form:

```
.[] | { projectId, label : (.labels | to_entries) [] } 
    | [.projectId, .label.key, .label.value ]  
    | @csv
```

#### Approach

Essentially, the first filter creates an object for each label as follows:

```json
{
  "projectId": "windy-bearing-129522",
  "label": {
    "key": "env",
    "value": "test"
  }
}
```

The second filter produces the following which pipes into the `@csv` to get it in the format we need:

```json
[
  "windy-bearing-129522",
  "env",
  "test"
]
```

A few things to note:

- We use the `to_entries` function to convert every label to be of the form `{ key : "some-key", value: "some-value" }`.
- The `[]` operator in the `label : (.labels | to_entries) []` is the one that makes it so that multiple labels under the same projects actually become separate objects.
- The `--raw-output` flag does not escape the quotes around the strings.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my problem is that the labels are not the same on every project. THAT is my main problem (lazy project owners :p) anyway, thanks again for the help, this response will help me in other related matters...

Comment: @JuanToroMarty - This solution outputs a row for every label in every project along with the label's value. And so, this works even if the label names on different projects are different. If it helps, in order to arrange the output to be such that the project names are rows and label names are headers (or vice-versa), you could import the CSV output this solution produces into Excel or another spreadsheet program and build a pivot table.